# How to configure XCode 8.3.2 on macOS 10.13.5 to develop application using wxWidgets 3.1.1?

Tags: xcode8, wxwidgets

I have used Terminal to build wxWidgets in Cocoa.

I am not clear what would be XCode settings so that I can start developing applications.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add the output of `wx-config --cxxflags` to the preprocessor defines/include directories build settings in Xcode and the output of `wx-config --libs` to the linker options. Unfortunately Xcode doesn't allow specifying the script to run directly in these options, so you need to copy and paste output from the terminal to it manually and -- which is the really annoying part -- remember to update it whenever it changes, e.g. after upgrading to a newer wxWidgets version.

Comment: wxWidgets book states that "_From the Settings drop-down menu, choose Language under GNU C/C++ Compiler, and find the Other C++ Flags option. This is where you will paste the results of using wx-config --cxxflags from the command line_" but @VZ. has written about adding --cxxflags in preprocessor defines. Lemme try that.

Comment: @Vibhor, the book is outdated as it was written a long time ago. Just follow Vadim suggestion.

Comment: "wx/wxprec.h" not found even if I gave '../configure --with-macosx-version-min=10.12 '